# How to convert a python function to kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to convert code from python to kotlin.

Don't know how to write this solution to be in Kotlin:

```
error=sum(int(parity_list) * (2 ** i) for i, parity_list in enumerate(parity_list[::-1]))
```

This is what it looks like in python

```
# coding=windows-1251

from traceback import print_tb


print('Введите полученный код Хэмминга')
d=input()
data=list(d)
data.reverse()
c,ch,j,r,error,h,parity_list,h_copy=0,0,0,0,0,[],[],[]
 
for k in range(0,len(data)):
        p=(2**c)
        h.append(int(data[k]))
        h_copy.append(data[k])
        if(p==(k+1)):
            c=c+1
        print("h = ", h)
        print("hCopy = ", h_copy)
        print("--------------------")
for parity in range(0,(len(h))):
        ph=(2**ch)
        print('ph =', ph)
        if(ph==(parity+1)):
         
            startIndex=ph-1
            i=startIndex
            print("i = ",i )
            toXor=[]
            
            print('len(h) = ', len(h) )
            while(i<len(h)):
                block=h[i:i+ph]
                toXor.extend(block)
                print('block = ', block )
                print('toXor =', toXor)
                i+=2*ph
                print('i = ', i)
                
 
            print('----')
            ch+=1

parity_list.reverse()

error=sum(int(parity_list) * (2 ** i) for i, parity_list in enumerate(parity_list[::-1]))
    
   
if((error)==0):
        print('В полученном коде Хэмминга нет ошибок')
 
elif((error)>=len(h_copy)):
        print('Ошибка не может быть обнаружена')
else:
        print('Error is in',error,'bit')
 
        if(h_copy[error-1]=='0'):
            h_copy[error-1]='1'
 
        elif(h_copy[error-1]=='1'):
            h_copy[error-1]='0'
            print('После исправления код Хэмминга: - ')
        h_copy.reverse()
        print(int(''.join(map(str, h_copy))))
```

Here is what I did in kotlin

```
@file:Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")

import kotlin.math.pow

fun main() {
    println("Введите полученный код Хэмминга: ")
    val d = readLine()!!
    val raz = d.toMutableList()
    val data = raz.reversed()
    println(data)
    var (c: Int, ch: Int, j: Int, r: Int, error: Int) = List(5) { 0 }
    val h: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    val parityList: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    val hCopy: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

        for (k in 0 until data.size) {
            val p = 2.0.pow(c)
            val k = data[k].toString()
            h.add(k.toInt())
            hCopy.add(k)



            if (p.toInt() == (k + 1).toInt()) c += 1

    }
    println("h = $h")
    println("hCopy = $hCopy")
    println("--------------------")

    for(parity in 0 until h.size){
        val ph =  (2.0.pow(ch)).toInt()
        println("ph = $ph")

        if (ph == (parity + 1)) {
            val startIndex = ph - 1
            var i = startIndex
            println("i = $i" )
            val toXor : ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()

            println("h.size = ${h.size}")
            while( i < h.size) {
                if ((i + ph) < h.size ) {
                    val block = h.slice(i until (i + ph))
                    toXor += block
                    i += 2 * ph
                    println("block = $block")
                    println("toXor = $toXor")
                    println("i  = $i")
                }
                else{
                    val kal = h.size
                    val block = h.slice(i until (kal))
                    toXor += block
                    i += 2 * ph
                    println("block = $block")
                    println("toXor = $toXor")
                    println("i  = $i")
                }

            }

            for (z in 1 until  toXor.size) {

                h[startIndex]=h[startIndex] xor toXor[z]
            }
            val m = data[parity].toString()
            parityList.add(m.toInt())
            println("------")
            ch+=1

            parityList.reversed()

         /*   error=sum(int(parity_list) * (2 ** i) for i, parity_list in enumerate(parity_list[::-1]))*/


       }

}

}
```

I don't understand how the `in enumerate` function works. I've searched the internet but haven't figured it all out.

Comment: `for i, val in enumerate(list)` is exactly the same as forEachIndexed (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html) in kotlin

Comment: Also look at `withIndex` property https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html)